# Standard Form of Hyperbolas

Tags: conic-sections

If I have the equation $9x^2-4y^2-72x=0 $ and I know that is a hyperbola, how would I find the standard form for this equation? I'm not sure how to convert this equation to the standard form of a hyperbola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9(x^2-8x) - 4y^2 = 0 \to 9(x-4)^2 - 4y^2 = 12^2 \to \dfrac{(x-4)^2}{4^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{6^2} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! How do I find the foci?

Comment: the center is $C = (4,0)$, and $c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \sqrt{4^2+6^2} = \sqrt{52} = 2\sqrt{13}\to F_1 = (4+2\sqrt{13},0), F_2 = (4-2\sqrt{13},0)$.